# How do I implemet an Hierarchical Tree using python?

Tags: python, hierarchical-trees

I'm working on a project that need to return a list of all the leafs (files) in a Tree. I don't know how to start and I need some help :)

I need to create a program that return all the files and folders in a current folder that running a process (my_program.py), the results should contain the root folder, files, subfolders and subfolders.files  etc....

Comment: first create class `Leaf`.

Comment: Give us a lot more details.

Comment: here you go more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
##Provide value of a path in filepath variable
filepath="C:\Users\poonamr\Desktop"
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(filepath)):
    print path
    if len(dirs)==0:
        print('No directories available in "' + path + '"')
    else:
        print dirs
    if len(files)==0:
        print('No files available in "' + dirs + '"') 
    else:
        print files
    print "\n"
```

Comment: thanks :)
but can you give me an example for a recursive way?

Comment: Ok, I tried. Let me know if you want anything more to be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def FileTree(Original_Path):
    dirlist=[]
    filelist=[]
    for dirnm in os.listdir(Original_Path):
        if os.path.isdir(Original_Path + "\\" + dirnm):
            dirlist.append(dirnm)
        else:
             filelist.append(dirnm)
    print "Folder    : " , Original_Path
    print "SubFolder : " , dirlist
    print "Files     : " , filelist
    print "\n\n"
    for dirSub in dirlist:
        FileTree(Original_Path+ "\\" + dirSub + "\\")


##Path specification    
Original_Path="C:\Users\poonamr\Desktop\Python Programs"
FileTree(Original_Path)
```